# Deploying apscheduler to production gives WebSocketBadStatusException Handshake status 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, django-rest-framework, websocket, gunicorn, apscheduler

I am getting **WebSocketBadStatusException Handshake status 502 Bad Gateway** error in the production after deploying a feature that uses apscheduler although apscheduler is working. I have drf as backend serving through nginx and gunicorn. I am using `channels.generic.websocke.AsyncWebsocketConsumer` to write websocket consumer.
My scheduler code:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor
from myapp.settings.production import DATABASES
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

jobstores = {
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=f'postgresql://{DATABASES["default"]["USER"]}:{quote_plus(DATABASES["default"]["PASSWORD"])}@{DATABASES["default"]["HOST"]}:{DATABASES["default"]["PORT"]}/{DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]}')
}

executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20)
}

job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 10
}

tscheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults)
```

How I am running scheduler:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from organizations.schedular import tscheduler

class OrganizationsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'organizations'

    def ready(self):
        tscheduler.start()
```

How I'm using scheduler:

```
#scheduling welcome email
run_at = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
tscheduler.add_job(
    send_welcome_email,
    'date',
    next_run_time=run_at,
    args=[
        organization_user_instance.user.email,
        organization_user_instance.user.profile.first_name
    ],
    id=f'welcome_{organization_user_instance.id}'
)
```

In my local machine websocket and scheduler are working fine. I struggle with the nginx and gunicorn configuration if anything related this feel free to guide me.